# Perl module test -- check for extraneous output to STDOUT/STDERR

Tags: perl, testing

I have a Perl module with many test cases already written using `Test::More`, calling `ok()`, `like()` and friends.

My module can print debug trace messages when enabled by a hidden option, and I want to verify that *no* messages are printed normally, to either STDOUT or STDERR, while running my existing test cases.  What is the best way to check that?

Answer (score 3):

There's [Test::NoWarnings](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::NoWarnings), but that complains if there is *any* output on standard error. If you want some output, then you have to do more work to figure that out on your own.

The [Test::Output](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Output) module can capture standard output and standard error, but then it's up to you to judge what's expected and what's not expected. If you want absolutely no output, that's easy. Grab the output from both filehandles and check that it's empty.

Typically, I find that this sort of task is so situation-dependent that I just get the output and sort it out myself.   If I can engineer the code to use a particular logging or output mechanism, I have a few options:

- the logging output can look like a log message, so any lines that don't look like a log message might be unwanted output
- I can redirect the logging output to somewhere else (/dev/null, whatever), so anything left over must be extra.
- I often do the same thing with standard output. Instead of writing to STDOUT directory, I have a filehandle set up for normal output. In normal cases, that's just another name for STDOUT, but I can make it [IO::Null](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Null). Then, as before, anything extra in standard output is suspicious.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  But don't you have to know the format of output from "ok()" and friends to allow those to pass through?

Comment: You don't use ok(), you use the functions in the Test:: module instead.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to rewrite 100s of test cases which currently use ok() etc. as provided by Test::More and friends.

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite anything, you aren't going to be able to do things differently.